# Парсинг сайта с JS

Tags: javascript, python, парсер

Ребят, только начал вникать в *Parsing*, помогите пожалуйста. Не могу получить необходимые элементы на сайте https://www.livesport.com/ru/football/, на сколько понял они подгружаются *JS*, но как получить совсем не понял...
`<div> id="live-table"` после него `<div class='filters'>` и `<selection class='event mobile'>` именно то что хотелось бы получить.

Не прошу писать за меня, но если есть возможность, подтолкните в нужную сторону. Заранее спасибо!

```
import requests
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def get_first_events():
    headers = {
        "user-agent": "Mozilla / 5.0(Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit / 537.36(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome / "
                      "99.0.4844.51 Safari / 537.36"
    }

    url = "https://www.livesport.com/ru/football/"
    r = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers)

    # soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "lxml")
    with open('test_livesport.html', 'w', encoding="UTF-8") as file:
        file.write(r.text)




def main():
    get_first_events()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: селенимум используйте

Comment: Пробую, не понимаю что дельше), вроде получаю файл с paje_sourse но таких названий классов как в html найти не могу.